# log4j MDC Loader java1() returns true on jdk11

Tags: java, log4j, mdc, java-11

Since the update to Java 11 I am struggling with a problem, that MDC variables are not being logged.

I debugged the logger and saw, that org.apache.log4j.MDC.java1() returns true on Java 11 and since it's true, no variables will be set due to:

```
private void put0(String key, Object o) {
    if (!this.java1 && this.tlm != null) {
        Hashtable ht = (Hashtable)((ThreadLocalMap)this.tlm).get();
        if (ht == null) {
            ht = new Hashtable(7);
            ((ThreadLocalMap)this.tlm).set(ht);
        }

        ht.put(key, o);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this or is there a new version of the dependency that fixes this? I tried 1.8.0-beta2 but the problem is the same.

Comment: The bug is here : https://github.com/cbcp9189/apache-log4j-1.2.17/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/helpers/Loader.java#L42
if java.version returns just "11", MDC fail, if it returns "11.0.4" MDC work

Comment: A solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69822992/why-log4j-stop-running-mdc-logic-if-java-version-is-11-11-1x-etc/72147021?noredirect=1#comment127476184_72147021