# Why log4j stop running MDC logic if Java version is 11, 11.1x, etc

Tags: java, log4j, mdc

I use MDC for helping log4j loging more information. Everything works well until I updated java version to 11.
This is my log4j config (pseodo code)

```
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern = [%-4p] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] [%X{request-id}] %l %m%n
```

This what I did for MDC

```
MDC.put("request-id","example-request-id")
```

By expectation, there should be request-id being logged. However it doesn't work if Java version is 11.

**Following is my findings from log4j code.**

There is a code in "org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader" to set `java1`,

```
    String prop = OptionConverter.getSystemProperty("java.version", null);
    
    if(prop != null) {
      int i = prop.indexOf('.');
      if(i != -1) { 
        if(prop.charAt(i+1) != '1')
        java1 = false;
      } 
    }
```

And then, some code in "org.apache.log4j.MDC#MDC" to stop logic.

```
void put0(String key, Object o) {
    if(java1 || tlm == null) {
      return;
    }
...
}
```

In summary, the MDC wouldn't work if the java version were 11,12,13,..., 11.1x, 12.1x,..., ect. Isn't this look like a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug. However, Log4j is marked as end-of-life since August 5, 2015 (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) and

> Users of Log4j 1 are recommended to upgrade to Apache Log4j 2

Specifically the problem with MDC and Java 9 is well known: [Log4j 1.2 is broken on Java 9](https://blogs.apache.org/logging/entry/moving_on_to_log4j_2), but it is unlikely that anyone will fix this ever.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the story. 
After read into the link, I would try to use log4j 2.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't switch to log4j2 for whatever reason or can't use another log provider, then you can copy the [org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j1/blob/v1_2_17/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/helpers/Loader.java) class from log4j1 into your project keeping the original package name (org.apache.log4j.helpers).

Then in the `Loader.java` inside your project:

- comment the part of the static block that deals with the java version, [here](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j1/blob/v1_2_17/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/helpers/Loader.java#L42-L50);
- comment the `boolean java1 = true` class variable;
- change the `isJava1()` method to always return `true`;
- locations that reference the `java1` variable must call the `isJava1()` method.

Now MDC works on Log4j1 + Java9+.

Comment: You can also switch to [reload4j](https://reload4j.qos.ch/). Version 1.2.18.0 fixes the MDC bug.